# Why can't my com.vaadin.UI import be resolved?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, vaadin

Im trying to import `com.vaddin.ui` into my Spring Boot Maven java application but it will not resolve my import. When I try to extend UI with MyView class, it keeps importing `com.vaadin.flow.component.UI`. There is no option for `com.vaadin.ui`.

[image: Import Can't be Resolved]

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.thompson</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BuildFirstBootStrap</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>12.0.6</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Does anyone see a problem within my dependencies or know what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UI` class has been moved to that new package since Vaadin 10. But you don't need to extend `UI` anymore. You have to use the `@Route` annotation on a Vaadin component. For example:

```
@Route("")
public class UsersView extends VerticalLayout {

    public UsersView() {
        add(new Text("It works!"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`com.vaadin.flow.component.UI` is the correct import with the Vaadin version in your `pom.xml`. In previous Vaadin versions, the import was `com.vaadin.ui.UI`, but it has never been `com.vaadin.UI`.